# How do I use my Defines in order?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I was wondering how I would put my defines in an order so when the user wants to restart the program it starts from where it left off.

The example I have is as follows:

```
import time

def problems():
    user = raw_input ("Hello there! would you like to run a troubleshoot to try and resolve the issue with your phone? (Y/N)")
    if user == "Y":
        print "running trouble shooting program..."
        time.sleep(1)
        wet()
    if user == "N":
        print "closing the program..."
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()
    else:
        print "input not recognised try again!"
        time.sleep(1)
        problems()

def wet():
    wet = raw_input ("Have you got the phone wet (Y/N)")
    if wet == "Y":
        print "Try putting the phone in some rice or cous cous for 24 hours"
        time.sleep(1)
        resolved()
    if wet == "N":
        resolved()
        print "Ouputting next question..."
        time.sleep(1)
        screen()
    else:
        print "input not recognised try again!"
        time.sleep()
        wet()

def virus():
     wet = raw_input ("Has the phone got a virus? (Y/N)")
    if wet == "Y":
        print "Do a factory reset of the phone."
        time.sleep(1)
        resolved()
    if wet == "N":
        resolved()
        print "Ouputting next question..."
        time.sleep(1)
        virus()
    else:
        print "input not recognised try again!"
        time.sleep()
        wet()


def resolved():
    yes = raw_input ("Would you like to continue?(Y/N)")
    if yes == "N":
        print "Thankyou for using this trouble shoot, closing the program..."
        time.sleep(1)
        quit()
    if yes == "Y":
        print "Restarting troubleshoot programming..."
        time.sleep(1)
    else:
        print "input not recognised try again!"
        resolved()

problems()
```

What I want to achieve with this code is to reset it to where the user finished answering his/her previous question. For example if the user received an answer for their phone being wet it would then run the define that allows them the option to leave or carry on. If they wanted to carry on it would then proceed to the next define. Please bear in mind I am planning on adding more defines so I do require a general order that can be continued following the users input.

Comment: Please call things by their proper names. These are functions, not "defines".

Comment: The word is *function* not *define*. Your problem isn't with the order your functions are defined, but in the order they are called. What you are looking for is persistence - you have to save state somehow to disk storage. You could probably get away with a simple text file for your program.

Comment: I agree with  juanpa.arrivillaga and propose to use configparser: https://wiki.python.org/moin/ConfigParserExamples